# Display the objects from all users in django without login on html page

Tags: python, html, django

I couldn't display the songs of all users on homepage. I want to display them like Youtube or other audio streaming sites directly on homepage without any login. I tried `objects.all()` nothing happens.

Please tell me what to write on `views.py` and what `html` template in `homepage.html`. I'm using `Python 3` and `django 1.10`.

**This is my models.py:**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.FileField()
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    audio_file = models.FileField(default='')
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

**This is my views.py(*not all shown*):**

```
def create_album(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'music/login.html')
    else:
        form = AlbumForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            album = form.save(commit=False)
            album.user = request.user
            album.album_logo = request.FILES['album_logo']
            file_type = album.album_logo.url.split('.')[-1]
            file_type = file_type.lower()
            if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
                context = {
                    'album': album,
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Image file must be PNG, JPG, or JPEG',
                }
                return render(request, 'music/create_album.html', context)
            album.save()
            return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album': album})
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, 'music/create_album.html', context)


def create_song(request, album_id):

form = SongForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
if form.is_valid():
    albums_songs = album.song_set.all()
    for s in albums_songs:
        if s.song_title == form.cleaned_data.get("song_title"):
            context = {
                'album': album,
                'form': form,
                'error_message': 'You already added that song',
            }
            return render(request, 'music/create_song.html', context)
    song = form.save(commit=False)
    song.album = album
    song.audio_file = request.FILES['audio_file']
    file_type = song.audio_file.url.split('.')[-1]
    file_type = file_type.lower()
    if file_type not in AUDIO_FILE_TYPES:
        context = {
            'album': album,
            'form': form,
            'error_message': 'Audio file must be WAV, MP3, or OGG',
        }
        return render(request, 'music/create_song.html', context)

    song.save()
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album': album})
context = {
    'album': album,
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'music/create_song.html', context)

def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'music/homepage.html')
    else:
        albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        song_results = Song.objects.all()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            albums = albums.filter(
                Q(album_title__icontains=query) |
                Q(artist__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            song_results = song_results.filter(
                Q(song_title__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            return render(request, 'music/index.html', {
                'albums': albums,
                'songs': song_results,
            })
        else:
            return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'albums': albums})


def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'music/login.html', context)


def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
                return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'albums': albums})
            else:
                return render(request, 'music/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'music/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
    return render(request, 'music/login.html')


def register(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
                return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'albums': albums})
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'music/register.html', context)


def songs(request, filter_by):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'music/login.html')
    else:
        try:
            song_ids = []
            for album in Album.objects.filter(user=request.user):
                for song in album.song_set.all():
                    song_ids.append(song.pk)
            users_songs = Song.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)
            if filter_by == 'favorites':
                users_songs = users_songs.filter(is_favorite=True)
        except Album.DoesNotExist:
            users_songs = []
        return render(request, 'music/songs.html', {
            'song_list': users_songs,
            'filter_by': filter_by,
        })

class HomePage(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/homepage.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Song.objects.all()
```

**urls.py:**

```
admin.autodiscover()

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),

#all auth urls
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
#Admin Urls
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    url(r'^login_user/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^logout_user/$', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<song_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
    url(r'^songs/(?P<filter_by>[a-zA_Z]+)/$', views.songs, name='songs'),
    url(r'^create_album/$', views.create_album, name='create_album'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/create_song/$', views.create_song, name='create_song'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/delete_song/(?P<song_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete_song, name='delete_song'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite_album/$', views.favorite_album, name='favorite_album'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/delete_album/$', views.delete_album, name='delete_album'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should put the default url at last

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

this url should be the last url in urls.py

then in your views you have at index() function

```
def index(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated(): # Edit HERE if authenticated                            
    song_results = Song.objects.all()
    albums = Album.objects.all()    
    return render(request, 'music/index.html', {
            'albums': albums,
            'songs': song_results,
        })
else:
    albums = Album.objects.all()
    song_results = Song.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        albums = albums.filter(
            Q(album_title__icontains=query) |
            Q(artist__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
        song_results = song_results.filter(
            Q(song_title__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
        return render(request, 'music/homepage.html', {
            'albums': albums,
            'songs': song_results,
        })
    else:
        return render(request, 'music/homepage.html', {'albums': albums})
```

If the user is not authenticated then you should pass whole to the `homepage.html` otherwise if authenticated `index.html` You probably made the condition opposite of want you wanted

In `homepage.html` you are passing `albums` and `songs` so

```
<html>
<body>

{% if albums %}
  {% for album in albums %}
    {{ album.album_title }} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if songs %}
  {% for song in songs %}
    {{ song.song_title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The way I intended was index.html as the first page after login and homepage.html as the first page before login.

Comment: then just interchange the name in views.index

Comment: What should I write in html template?

Comment: It created an error:
TypeError at /

'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:  1.10.5
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Comment: this line :
        albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)

shows that error in views.py

Comment: Its because you are filtering `Album` by `request.user` which is Anonymous ATM,  make `albums = Album.objects.all()` in views, and check

Comment: The albums are now shown in homepage.html but when logged in the search is not working and after logging in the user's albums disappears if any other links are visited. I guess I'm too noob.

Comment: to make `albums` appear in every page you have to pass it to every html page in the views, and for logged in user you have to pass `albums` the same way in check my edit. Its the same way as you pass it to `Anonymous` users.

Answer (score 0):

modify your first(root) url pattern with

```
 url(r'^$', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
```

Comment: Why? It's not class based.

Comment: In the views.py file there is a class named HomePage which redirect to homepage.html after retrieving all the song objects. Definitely all the other routes are FB.

Comment: I got huge error while editing it. I added that line though, still it didn't work. What should I write in views.py and in html template?